# Combine text using delimiter for duplicate column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

What im trying to achieve is to combine `Name` into one value using comma delimiter whenever `Country` column is duplicated, and sum the values in `Salary` column.

Current input :

```
pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'John',1: 'Steven',2: 'Ibrahim',3: 'George',4: 'Nancy',5: 'Mo',6: 'Khalil'},
              'Country': {0: 'USA',1: 'UK',2: 'UK',3: 'France',4: 'Ireland',5: 'Ireland',6: 'Ireland'},
              'Salary': {0: 100, 1: 200, 2: 200, 3: 100, 4: 50, 5: 100, 6: 10}})

    Name    Country  Salary
0   John    USA      100
1   Steven  UK       200
2   Ibrahim UK       200
3   George  France   100
4   Nancy   Ireland  50
5   Mo      Ireland  100
6   Khalil  Ireland  10
```

Expected output :

Row 1 & 2 (in inputs) got grupped into one since `Country` column is duplicated & `Salary` column is summed up.

Tha same goes for Row 4,5 & 6.

```
    Name               Country  Salary
0   John               USA       100
1   Steven, Ibrahim    UK        400
2   George             France    100
3   Nancy, Mo, Khalil  Ireland   160
```

What i have tried, but im not sure how to combine text in `Name` column :

```
df.groupby(['Country'],as_index=False)['Salary'].sum()

[Out:]

    Country Salary
0   France  100
1   Ireland 160
2   UK      400
3   USA     100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `groupby()` and `agg()`:

```
out=df.groupby('Country',as_index=False).agg({'Name':', '.join,'Salary':'sum'})
```

If needed unique values of 'Name' column then use :

```
out=(df.groupby('Country',as_index=False)
       .agg({'Name':lambda x:', '.join(set(x)),'Salary':'sum'}))
```

**Note:** use `pd.unique()` in place of `set()` if order of unique values is important

output of `out`:

```
    Country         Name               Salary
0   France          George              100
1   Ireland         Nancy, Mo, Khalil   160
2   UK              Steven, Ibrahim     400
3   USA             John                100
```

Comment: I like how, despite posting the same answer on the same time, we tried to make it sightly different ;) +1

Comment: @mozway lol yeah I also noticed when refreshed the page...+1 to you too **;)**

Answer (score 3):

Use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df.groupby(['Country'], as_index=False).agg({'Name': ', '.join, 'Salary':'sum'})
```

And to get the columns in order you can add `[df.columns]` to the pipe:

```
df.groupby(['Country'], as_index=False).agg({'Name': ', '.join, 'Salary':'sum'})[df.columns]
```

```
    Name               Country  Salary
0   John               USA       100
1   Steven, Ibrahim    UK        400
2   George             France    100
3   Nancy, Mo, Khalil  Ireland   160
```